# Perl how to check if array is still empty?

Tags: arrays, perl

This should be simple hopefully. I initialize an empty array, do a grep and place the results (if any) in it, and then check if it's empty. Like so:

```
my @match = ();
@match = grep /$pattern/, @someOtherArray;
if (#match is empty#) {
    #do something!
}
```

What's the standard way of doing this?

Comment: You can define and initialize @match on the same line - `my @match = grep etc.`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You will see all of these idioms used to test whether an array is empty.

```
if (!@match)
if (@match == 0)
if (scalar @match == 0)
```

In scalar context, an array is evaluated as the number of elements it contains.

Comment: Don't forget `unless ( @match )`

Comment: [Do forget `unless (@match)`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl::Critic::Policy::ControlStructures::ProhibitUnlessBlocks). (but that's just, like, my opinion, man)

Comment: Are the converses to these also true? If you wanted to control behavior for when at least one element was present, I'm assuming it would be `if (@match)` and `if (@match != 0)` but I thought I ought to check

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an arrayref instead of an array say for e.g.

```
my $existing_match = data_layer->find('Sale',{id => $id});
```

Say above returns an array, then use:

```
if( scalar(@$existing_match) == 0)
```

Comment: The boolean context already takes care of that so writing it all out is redundant.

Answer (score -3):

I've also found that this works too, but I'm not sure if it's documented:

```
if ($#match == -1)
```

Comment: Please, no one ever do this. :)  It's always `if (@match) { }` or `if (not @match) { }` or `if (! @match) { }`.

Comment: @lordadmira What about `if ($#match < -0.5) {}`?

Comment: In other words, is your objection _only_ that it's dangerous to test for exact equality of two integers in a language where variables are not clearly typed as integer or floating-point?